# Creating a CD auto-start dialog

Tags: dialog, implementation, autostart

For me, compact discs and these customized auto-start dialogs are somewhat outdated and waste...
However, I *have* to create such a dialog as an index for a CD consisting of a few PDF files. Making one to work on Microsoft Windows is quite easy. As there might be users from different platforms (Unix, Apple,...), the question raises how to offer them such a (auto-starting) dialog as well.

Java is of course an option, but I think it's overloaded and naturally too slow for this purpose.

Now, I think of a single webpage that will appear in the local browser. Using all these web standards this could a very creative, light-weight approach working on most systems.

Do you see any problems that might occur here? Probably, there is a different and more elegant solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really recommend something precisely but I've seen lots of CD open a Adobe Flash dialog. It's also been a long time I've played around with flash but I think they're a setting in File > Publish that allows you to export to a dialog.

The CD auto-start is an `autorun.ini` file added to the root of the CD. You could create a folder on the CD named `autorun` or something. Insert all your Flash/HTML files then point the `open` parameter of the autorun.ini file to an HTML/Flash file.

Some documentation below (or Google “autorun.ini”).
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818804

Notice however not all computer will have Flash installed by default.